# How to copy files containing a specific phrase to another directory?

Tags: files, directory, log, csv

I have a huge directory with log-files and want to move files WITH a specific "phrase" in it.

i.e.

```
log1.csv ------ containing word "xzy"
log2.csv ------ containing word "abc"
log3.csv ------ containing word "xzy"
..
log1000.csv ------ containing word "123"
```

Now I want to move (or copy) all `*.csv` WITH "xyz" in it to a new directory

What is the best solution?

Answer (score 3):

`find` and `grep`:

```
find /dir/ -type f -name 'log*.csv' -exec grep -q 'xyz' {} \; -exec mv -t /target/ {} \;
```

- `find /dir/ -type f -name 'log*.csv'` finds all `log<anything>.csv` files inside directory `/dir`
- `-exec grep -q 'xyz' {} \;` runs `grep` on each found file to match for Regex pattern `xyz`
- `-exec mv -t /target/ {} \;` moves the matched files (based on exit status of `grep`; success (`0`) means matched) from previous step into target directory `/target`

Comment: grep is one of the most useful things in the Unix world (the other is NetCat :) ). People should learn it before almost anything else.